# I am unable to send coins from my Metamask wallet (details below). Thx in advance

Tags: metamask, wallets

I am not able to send any coins from my Metamask wallet. After hitting Send, the next screen shows two rectangles - each associated with the accounts to be used (the ‘from’ account, and the ‘to’ account). After entering an amount of whatever currency, I am no longer prompted to do anything, effectively disabling my ability to send / spend.

Comment: It does work here. Can you provide more details about the dialogs? I'd suggest try contacting Metamask customer support.

Comment: Thank you. I have contacted Metamask Support, who informed me of a week - long wait.

Comment: I'd suggest to backup the seed phrase, and reinstall Metamask, or try installing in other browser. Another option is using it from MyEtherWallet or MyCrypto that have the option to connect with MM.

Comment: TY. A little nervous regarding un- / re-install. The prob is mobile but desktop works after I undid ‘system restore’ and got my wallet back (another issue I had, addressed in another post).